# Converting number into words using if else

Tags: c++, numbers, cpu-word

I am a beginner in c++. I have written a program to convert numbers into words. I am getting wrong output for numbers between 11-19 and numbers like this, 20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90. I also tried to add else statement between last two if statements so that It does not execute all the if statements even if the first if is true but it gives me an error that "else without a previous if".

```
//This program converts number into words
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int number,unit,ten;
    cout<<"Please enter any number between 0-99: ";
    cin>>number;
    ten=number/10;
    unit=number%10;
    if(number<0 | number>99)
        cout<<"Number is out of range";
    if(number>=11 && number <=19);
    {
        if(number==11) cout<<"eleven"; 
        if(number==12) cout<<"twelve";
        if(number==13) cout<<"thirteen"; 
        if(number==14) cout<<"fourteen";
        if(number==15) cout<<"fifteen";
        if(number==16) cout<<"sixteen";
        if(number==17) cout<<"seventeen";
        if(number==18) cout<<"eighteen";
        if(number==19) cout<<"ninteen";
    }
    if(ten>=2 && ten<=9)    
    {   
        if(ten==1) cout<<"ten";
        if(ten==2) cout<<"twenty";
        if(ten==3) cout<<"thirty";
        if(ten==4) cout<<"fourty";
        if(ten==5) cout<<"fifty";
        if(ten==6) cout<<"sixty";
        if(ten==7) cout<<"seventy";
        if(ten==8) cout<<"eighty";
        if(ten==9) cout<<"ninty";
    }
    if(unit>=0 && unit <=9)
    {
        if(unit==0) cout<<" zero";
        if(unit==1) cout<<" one";
        if(unit==2) cout<<" two";
        if(unit==3) cout<<" three";
        if(unit==4) cout<<" four";
        if(unit==5) cout<<" five";
        if(unit==6) cout<<" six";
        if(unit==7) cout<<" seven";
        if(unit==8) cout<<" eight";
        if(unit==9) cout<<" nine";
    }
}
```

Output 1:-

```
Please enter any number between 0-99: 12
twelve two
```

Output 2:-

```
Please enter any number between 0-99: 30
thirty zero
```

Comment: [Turn on compiler warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zpe_cK)

Comment: There is another bug in your code, but you happen to get lucky that it doesn't bite you. You're using a bitwise OR `|` when you meant to use a logical OR `||`: `if (number < 0 || number > 99)` The reason it still appears to work is a coincidence of a few historical reasons.

Comment: Code style: always have a space between `if` and its opening `(`. Also a space between operands: `unit == 7` not `unit==7`. I know it sounds irrelevant, but this is your craft, treat it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a semicolon `;` after the second `if`. And also, you should use `||` instead of `|`. Also you should exlude the case when `ten==1`.

```
//This program converts number into words
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int number,unit,ten;
    cout<<"Please enter any number between 0-99: ";
    cin>>number;
    ten=number/10;
    unit=number%10;
    if(number<0 || number>99)
    {
        cout<<"Number is out of range";
    }
    if(ten == 1)
    {
        if(number==10) cout<<"ten"; 
        if(number==11) cout<<"eleven"; 
        if(number==12) cout<<"twelve";
        if(number==13) cout<<"thirteen"; 
        if(number==14) cout<<"fourteen";
        if(number==15) cout<<"fifteen";
        if(number==16) cout<<"sixteen";
        if(number==17) cout<<"seventeen";
        if(number==18) cout<<"eighteen";
        if(number==19) cout<<"ninteen";
    }
    else {   
        if(ten==2) cout<<"twenty";
        if(ten==3) cout<<"thirty";
        if(ten==4) cout<<"fourty";
        if(ten==5) cout<<"fifty";
        if(ten==6) cout<<"sixty";
        if(ten==7) cout<<"seventy";
        if(ten==8) cout<<"eighty";
        if(ten==9) cout<<"ninty";

        // ****
        if(unit==0 && ten ==0) cout<<" zero";
        if(unit==1) cout<<" one";
        if(unit==2) cout<<" two";
        if(unit==3) cout<<" three";
        if(unit==4) cout<<" four";
        if(unit==5) cout<<" five";
        if(unit==6) cout<<" six";
        if(unit==7) cout<<" seven";
        if(unit==8) cout<<" eight";
        if(unit==9) cout<<" nine";
    }
}
```

Output for all cases:

```
Please enter any number between 0-99: -1
Number is out of range

Please enter any number between 0-99: 0
 zero

Please enter any number between 0-99: 1
 one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 2
 two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 3
 three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 4
 four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 5
 five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 6
 six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 7
 seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 8
 eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 9
 nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 10
ten

Please enter any number between 0-99: 11
eleven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 12
twelve

Please enter any number between 0-99: 13
thirteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 14
fourteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 15
fifteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 16
sixteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 17
seventeen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 18
eighteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 19
ninteen

Please enter any number between 0-99: 20
twenty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 21
twenty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 22
twenty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 23
twenty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 24
twenty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 25
twenty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 26
twenty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 27
twenty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 28
twenty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 29
twenty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 30
thirty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 31
thirty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 32
thirty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 33
thirty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 34
thirty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 35
thirty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 36
thirty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 37
thirty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 38
thirty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 39
thirty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 40
fourty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 41
fourty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 42
fourty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 43
fourty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 44
fourty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 45
fourty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 46
fourty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 47
fourty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 48
fourty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 49
fourty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 50
fifty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 51
fifty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 52
fifty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 53
fifty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 54
fifty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 55
fifty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 56
fifty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 57
fifty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 58
fifty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 59
fifty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 60
sixty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 61
sixty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 62
sixty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 63
sixty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 64
sixty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 65
sixty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 66
sixty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 67
sixty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 68
sixty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 69
sixty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 70
seventy

Please enter any number between 0-99: 71
seventy one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 72
seventy two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 73
seventy three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 74
seventy four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 75
seventy five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 76
seventy six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 77
seventy seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 78
seventy eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 79
seventy nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 80
eighty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 81
eighty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 82
eighty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 83
eighty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 84
eighty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 85
eighty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 86
eighty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 87
eighty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 88
eighty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 89
eighty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 90
ninty

Please enter any number between 0-99: 91
ninty one

Please enter any number between 0-99: 92
ninty two

Please enter any number between 0-99: 93
ninty three

Please enter any number between 0-99: 94
ninty four

Please enter any number between 0-99: 95
ninty five

Please enter any number between 0-99: 96
ninty six

Please enter any number between 0-99: 97
ninty seven

Please enter any number between 0-99: 98
ninty eight

Please enter any number between 0-99: 99
ninty nine

Please enter any number between 0-99: 100
Number is out of range
```

Comment: Good catch! Ironically that second `if` is completely unnecessary since the `if` statements in its body handle its job.

Comment: Now it works for numbers between 11 and 19 but still it is giving wrong output for numbers 10,20,30 and so on. Output for 30 is "Thirty zero".

Comment: @MoazAli, Thanks for pointing out. I changed the program logic a bit and now it works for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `int main()` not `main()` and add `return 0;` in `int main()`
2. The line `if(number<0 | number>99)` should be `if(number<0 || number>99)`
3. The line `if(number>=11 && number <=19);` should be `if(number>=11 && number <=19)`
4. Before `if(ten>=2 && ten<=9)` should add `else`.

The follow `code` could work:

```
//This program converts number into words
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int number,unit,ten;
    cout<<"Please enter any number between 0-99: ";
    cin>>number;
    ten=number/10;
    unit=number%10;
    if(number<0 || number>99)
        cout<<"Number is out of range";
    if(number>=11 && number <=19)
    {
        if(number==11) cout<<"eleven";
        if(number==12) cout<<"twelve";
        if(number==13) cout<<"thirteen";
        if(number==14) cout<<"fourteen";
        if(number==15) cout<<"fifteen";
        if(number==16) cout<<"sixteen";
        if(number==17) cout<<"seventeen";
        if(number==18) cout<<"eighteen";
        if(number==19) cout<<"ninteen";
    } else {
        if(ten>=2 && ten<=9)
        {
            if(ten==1) cout<<"ten";
            if(ten==2) cout<<"twenty";
            if(ten==3) cout<<"thirty";
            if(ten==4) cout<<"fourty";
            if(ten==5) cout<<"fifty";
            if(ten==6) cout<<"sixty";
            if(ten==7) cout<<"seventy";
            if(ten==8) cout<<"eighty";
            if(ten==9) cout<<"ninty";
        }
        if(unit>=0 && unit <=9)
        {
            if(unit==0) cout<<" zero";
            if(unit==1) cout<<" one";
            if(unit==2) cout<<" two";
            if(unit==3) cout<<" three";
            if(unit==4) cout<<" four";
            if(unit==5) cout<<" five";
            if(unit==6) cout<<" six";
            if(unit==7) cout<<" seven";
            if(unit==8) cout<<" eight";
            if(unit==9) cout<<" nine";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with "add `return 0;` in `int main()`". It can be done of course, but in a stackoverflow question where concision is important, better let the compiler add it for you ;) upvoted still

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is actually right due to your `if`conditions. If you write down 3 `if`conditions, it will check the THREE of them. Also, take out the semicolon on the second if!

So the first one, 12, goes to the first `if`and prints "twelve".

Goes to the second `if`. `12/10`is `1.2`so as an int, it is `1. It does not go in the second if. It is not going in anyways due to the semicolon.

But it goes in the third one: `12%10`.

So it is as you have in your `ifs`!

Also, I am worried that this is working for you: `if(number<0 | number>99)`, as it should be `||`, and not `|`.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this a switch statement makes more sense. Try this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    for (int number = 1; number <= 99; number++)
    {
        int ten=number/10;
        int unit=number%10;
        if(number<0 || number>99)
        {
            cout<<"Number is out of range";
            return 1;
        }
        if(ten == 1)
        {
            switch ( number )
            {
            case 10: cout<<"ten"; break;
            case 11: cout<<"eleven"; break;
            case 12: cout<<"twelve"; break;
            case 13: cout<<"thirteen"; break;
            case 14: cout<<"fourteen"; break;
            case 15: cout<<"fifteen"; break;
            case 16: cout<<"sixteen"; break;
            case 17: cout<<"seventeen"; break;
            case 18: cout<<"eighteen"; break;
            case 19: cout<<"nineteen"; break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(ten>=2 && ten<=9)    
            {   
                switch (ten)
                {
                case 2: cout<<"twenty"; break;
                case 3: cout<<"thirty"; break;
                case 4: cout<<"fourty"; break;
                case 5: cout<<"fifty"; break;
                case 6: cout<<"sixty"; break;
                case 7: cout<<"seventy"; break;
                case 8: cout<<"eighty"; break;
                case 9: cout<<"ninty"; break;
                }
            }
            if ( unit != 0 and ten != 0 )
            {
                cout << " ";
            }
            switch ( unit )
            {
                case 0: if ( ten == 0 ) cout<<"zero"; break;
                case 1: cout<<"one"; break;
                case 2: cout<<"two"; break;
                case 3: cout<<"three"; break;
                case 4: cout<<"four"; break;
                case 5: cout<<"five"; break;
                case 6: cout<<"six"; break;
                case 7: cout<<"seven"; break;
                case 8: cout<<"eight"; break;
                case 9: cout<<"nine"; break;
            }
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've also found the following bugs:

1. you use the bitwise or `|` rather than the boolean or `||` in your first if statement. You also don't stop the rest of your code after printing `"Number is out of range"`, I've fixed this by returning.
2. There is a semicolon on the end of your second if statement, this if statement can also be simplified to `ten == 1`.
3. You need to prevent the rest of the code running after printing the 'teens, this can be done with `else`.
4. You never print `"ten"`, it should probably be printed with the 'teens but is printed with 20, 30 etc. but will never actually be printed due to the surrounding if statement.
5. You print "zero" after 20, 30, etc. This can be fixed by only printing `"zero"` if `ten` is `0`.
6. The if statement `if(unit>=0 && unit <=9)` will always be true so can be removed.